# How can I limit access to certain pages (admin) with js (node?)

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I’ve built a page for my business

http://www.dishcafecatering.com

I want to build a page off the main page so I can update the specials each day. Is this something that can be done in Vanilla js or will I need to use node or for that matter can I use firebase? I don’t want everyone to come to the site to have to be authenticated, but maybe just when they click on the admin link? Is there a way in firebase to check the email against data stored in the dB to see if they should have access?

Not specifically looking for the exact answer, but a point in the correct direction. Since I’ve already built the site, I don’t especially want to recode it all in node and express. I’m also a beginner in node and just an advanced beginner in HTML/CSS/JS.

Comment: Good job with the website! You can find write rules for Firestore here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started#writing_rules

Comment: Thank you, I will read though this tonight.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to use Node just for this purpose.

1. Set up an `/admin` page where the user is greeted by a Login form.
2. Set up firebase auth for admin with email and password in Firebase auth
3. Authenticate against this admin user setup
4. Setup Firebase security rules for Firestore

   ```
   service cloud {
     match /databases/{database}/recipes {
       match /<some_path>/ {
         allow write: if request.auth.uid != null;;
       }
     }
   }
   ```

   This allows write access only to users who are authenticated. If in any case you want authentication for other users, you can check `request.auth` variable for other identification parameters.

You can find this in docs here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions

Comment: Thanks I’ll try that tomorrow and see if I can get it to work. Appreciate it.